# Decreasing font size animation - how to avoid moving siblings

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I would make animation like this:

- start: big font
- animation: decrease font size
- end: casual font size

Problem: animated element moves others. How to avoid it?

EDIT:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LXVVPR

HTML

```
<div class='center'>
  <div class="container">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>
      <span class='animation'>2</span>
      <span> 3 </span>
      <span>4</span>
    </span>
    <span>5</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.center{
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;

}
.container{

  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  grid-gap: 20px;

  padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.animation{
  animation: winner-animation 2s ease-in 0s 2 normal none;    
} 

@keyframes winner-animation{
  0% { font-size: 70px }
  100% { font-size: 16px }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by animating [`transform: scale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) instead of `font-size`. Using some simple math, you can calculate the scale using the font sizes you desire to animate to and from: `70/16 = 4.375`.

This also has a performance benefit, since `transform` [is a GPU-accelerated CSS property](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/) while `font-size` is not.

**Edit:** Note that you must declare the animated element `inline-block` for `transform: scale()` to work.

```css
.center{
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;

}
.bar-container{

  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  grid-gap: 20px;

  padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.animation{
  display: inline-block;
  animation: winner-animation-scale 2s ease-in 0s infinite normal none;
}

@keyframes winner-animation{
  0% { font-size: 70px }
  100% { font-size: 16px }
}

@keyframes winner-animation-scale {
  0% { transform: scale(4.375); /* 70/16 */ }
  100% { transform: scale(1); }
}
```

```html
<div class='center'>
  <div class="container">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>
      <span class='animation'>2</span>
      <span> 3 </span>
      <span>4</span>
    </span>
    <span>5</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I need, thank You. Can You explain me, why it's necessary to use display: inline-block?

Comment: [Under the spec for CSS transforms](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/#terminology), non-replaced inline elements are not considered "transformable elements." Changing the display property to `inline-block` enables the transform.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT / COMPLETELY REWRITTEN:

1.) Change the HTML structure so that the 5 numbers are direct children of `.container` (i.e. remove the `span` which wraps the inner three)

2.) Change `grid-template-columns` for the container to `repeat(5, auto);` (i.e. now 5 children elements instead of three)

3.) Add a fixed width and `text-align: center` to *all* direct children of the container:

```
.container>span {
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```css
.center {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.container>span {
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
}
.animation {
  animation: winner-animation 2s ease-in 0s 2 normal none;
}

@keyframes winner-animation {
  0% {
    font-size: 70px
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 16px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='center'>
  <div class="container">
    <span>1</span>
    <span class='animation'>2</span>
    <span> 3 </span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I repaired one mistake in the source post. In this link: [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gQpOEa) I added Your tip, but span (which has 3 spans inside) still resizes with span.animation.

Comment: @3D_fun please note my completely rewritten answer